# How to put a return statement in lambda python with expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm planning to simplify my code without defining the function. Is it possible?

```
a = lambda x:1 if x>1 return x-1 else return x
```

output 0 = 0, 1=1 ,2=1 ,3=2

Comment: *Don't* use a `lambda`: `def a(x): return x - (x > 1)`

Comment: [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): "Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier."

Comment: ok Thank you @PEP8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is syntactically correct way to use lambdas in Python

```
>>> a = lambda x: x-1 if x>1 else x
>>> a(3)
2
>>> a(1)
1
>>> a(0)
0
>>> a(2)
1
```

For better understanding about lambdas visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

```
a = lambda x:1 if x>1 return x-1 else return x
```

This is syntactically wrong. If you want to use if else, inline to make it work like a ternary operator in other languages.
You will have to write:

```
# expression1 if condition else expression2
x-1 if x>1 else x
```

So it becomes:

```
a = lambda x: x-1 if x>1 else x
```

Remember lambda in python can only have a single line of code.

Comment: Thank very much it helps me alot